# Remove first part of file fullname

Tags: powershell

This is an update on 5/18/18:
Thank you to all who posted. Everyone has shared some great information. I was able to figure out a really simple solution using the DirectoryName once it finally clicked for me:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -path "c:\temp\testc" -Recurse 
$destshare = "C:\temp\testD\"
$Dest = ($file.DirectoryName.replace($file.directoryname, $destshare))
```

Original post below:

I am pulling the `.fullname` from a file using the `Get-Childitem` and am looking to **remove** the `server\sharename` from the source.

Using `$f.fullname.split('\)[X]` keeps the portion of the array that I select, but is there a way to **remove** the `\\server\share$` (`\\ECNFILE01\santana-carlos$\`)?

From:

```
\\ECNFILE11\Joe-smith-J$\work\O365 SOP - New User Account Creation BEANE EDITS and MARKUPS.docx
```

I want only:

```
\work\O365 SOP - New User Account Creation BEANE EDITS and MARKUPS.docx
```

The server\sharename will be different for each user: `\\ECNFILE11\Joe-smith-J$`, `\\ECNFILE9\user2$`, `\\ECNFILE1\user3`, etc...

Thanks

Comment: Note: *** The \\server\sharename will be different for each user so not able to define it and then remove it.

Comment: Maybe it is me but I read your question 3 times and I'm still not positive exactly what you want. Please edit your question and show a clear ***before*** and ***after*** example of what you want. Also you should show us what you have tried even if it doesn't work.

Comment: maybe $p.Split('$')[1]  - this will cut off server\sharename :)

Comment: $F.fullname.split('\)[0..1]  keeps the server\sharename.

Before:

\\ECNFILE11\Joe-smith-J$\work\O365 SOP - New User Account Creation BEANE EDITS and MARKUPS.docx

After:

work\O365 SOP - New User Account Creation BEANE EDITS and MARKUPS.docx

The server\sharename (\\ECNFILE11\Joe-smith-J$) will be different for each user (\\ECNFILE11\Joe-smith-J$, \\ECNFILE9\user2$, \\ECNFILE1\user3, etc...)

Comment: If I could link to SF, I would mark this a dup of: https://serverfault.com/questions/297690/how-to-split-parent-path-of-a-unc-path-by-using-powershell

Comment: Kory, this is *NOT* the same because I am not looking to keep the \\server\sharename, I am looking to discard it and keep the rest.

Comment: Why use `.fullname` at all, then? Just use `.name` instead and append the folder path?

Comment: Because I need the folders as well so they can be created when doing the copy-item. So source would be \\Server\Share\FolderA\File.ext.  Destination will be \\NewServer\NewShare\FolderA\File.ext

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the string to [URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx), and use make use of the `Host` and the `Segments` properties to build a string in the `\\server\share\` style that you want:

```
$URI = [URI]"\\ECNFILE11\Joe-smith-J$\work\O365 SOP - New User Account Creation BEANE EDITS and MARKUPS.docx"
Write-Output "\\$($URI.Host)\$($URI.Segments[1])"

> \\ecnfile11\Joe-smith-J$/
```

Windows will autocorrect `\` vs `/` in a UNC path, but you can always use replace to change this if you wish...

```
Write-Output "\\$($URI.host)\$($URI.Segments[1] -replace('/','\'))"

> \\ecnfile11\Joe-smith-J$\
```

---

To return the path without `\\server\share`

```
$UNC = "\\ECNFILE11\Joe-smith-J$\work\O365 SOP - New User Account Creation BEANE EDITS and MARKUPS.docx"
$URI = [URI]$UNC
$UNC -replace "^$([regex]::Escape("\\$($URI.host)\$($URI.Segments[1] -replace('/','\'))"))"

> work\O365 SOP - New User Account Creation BEANE EDITS and MARKUPS.docx
```

Comment: Thanks James, but I I a not looking to keep the server\sharename. I can do that through a simple .spit('\')[0..1].  I am looking to strip out and remove the \\server\sharename.

Comment: Yes just seen your edit that makes this clear. Hold on and I'll update.

Comment: Answer updated to reflect clarification on what you wanted returned.

Comment: Thank you to all who posted. Everyone has shared some great information. I was able to figure out a really simple solution using the DirectoryName once it finally clicked for me:


$file = Get-ChildItem -path "c:\temp\testc" -Recurse 
$destshare = "C:\temp\testD\"
$Dest = ($file.DirectoryName.replace($file.directoryname, $destshare))

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Split-Path` in a Do loop until it doesn't return anything and take the previous result which will then be be the last valid UNC path e.g. `\\server\share`. Then Regex replace that from the fullname

```
$Files = @('\\ECNFILE11\Joe-smith-J$\work\O365 SOP - New User Account Creation BEANE EDITS and MARKUPS.docx','\\ECNFILE01\santana-carlos$\!Archive!\cotr\Task Orders\OPS\OPS-TO-09-1\OPS-TO-2009-1 Extension\OPS-TO-2009-1 MOD6\OPS-TO-2009-2 MOD6 InitiationForm.doc')
foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $PathParent = $File 
    do {
        $PreviousParent = $PathParent
        $PathParent = Split-Path $PathParent -Parent
    }
    while ($PathParent)
    $File -replace "^$([regex]::Escape(PreviousParent))"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove `\\servername\sharename$` from network share path, you can simply take 
`Split('$\')[1]`

But if share is not administrative share (no `$` sign at the end of share name) 
then you have to split by `'\'`, remove first 4 rows, join rest with `\` between each.